# How to upgrade package.json or react libraries automatically?

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json, npx, npm-check-updates

How to upgrade packages in react application automatically using commands? I don't want to manually check every library in package.json and check its latest version. I want to upgrade my package.json at one shot.

Answer (score 4):

```
npm i -g npm-check-updates
ncu -u
npm install
```

Looks like [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check-updates)is the only way to make this happen now.

Comment: what if I need a specific version of react?

Answer (score 0):

> Upgrading libraries, frameworks in Javascript project is surely a tiresome and complex process. However, it has much more benefits in the long run and stability .

Here are the main reasons why upgrading libraries are important:

- **New features:** Most dependencies have a clear roadmap for new features.
- ️ **Performance improvements:** In addition to new features, performance improvements are also made frequently.
- **Fixed bugs:** Although it is normal to find bugs in libraries that you depend on, patch releases help fix these issues.
- **Security patches:** Security patches are one of the most important reasons to have your libraries up-to-date.

The manual process is too tiresome as you need to check for the latest version of each package. So make it easier we will be using two separate methods.

Using [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check-updates)

> **npm-check-updates upgrades your package.json dependencies to the *latest* versions, ignoring specified versions.**

Please follow the steps below -

- Install [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm-check-updates)
- Run `npm-check-updates` to list what packages are out of date
- Run `npm-check-updates -u` to update all the versions in your package.json
- Run `npm update` as usual to install the new versions of your packages based on the updated package.json

If you do not want to install npm-check-updates in machine, you can follow the steps below-

- run `npx npm-check-updates` (This will list down all the outdated packages in package.json)
- Run `ncu -u` to upgrade package.json
- `npm install` to install the packages

Check your project by running the application and verifying the up-gradation. There might be issues in your code that might as part of up-gradation. In such scenario please check the release notes of the package and make the due changes in code.